# Changing the order of Search Results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working with a WordPress website on which I want to improve the search engine. And I want to do this by changing the order of the search results. I am currently using the standard `<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>` which I believe shows Search Results depending on Publish date. I believe the easiest way would be to change the search wp-query that decides what posts are found but I do not know where this one is located. But if you have another way of solving this I would really appreciate this.

If you could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks, Ledung

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do raw query select with your custom condition right?
Here is the document from wordpress itself: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thanks will look into this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Your tip led me to this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41691/how-do-i-filter-the-search-results-order

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pre_get_posts-hook to change order and do all sort of magic to your search loop.

Multiple examples here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: I have not tried it yet but this looks really promising, Thanks alot for the tip :) I will hear back when I have tried it.